# nvim cannot render solarized theme

Tags: neovim

I've been trying to configure my neovim interface with a popular [solarized color theme](https://github.com/altercation/vim-colors-solarized). I use vim-plug to manage my plugins. And here's how it looks:

[image: a picture of my nvim interface]

As you can see, it's not working at all. I've solutions from similar problems but none of them works for me.

Here's my entire configuration:

```
syntax enable
set background=dark
call plug#begin('~/.config/nvim/bundle')
Plug 'Shougo/deoplete.nvim', { 'do': ':UpdateRemotePlugins' }
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdtree'
Plug 'scrooloose/nerdcommenter'
Plug 'christoomey/vim-tmux-navigator'
Plug 'zchee/deoplete-jedi'
Plug 'pangloss/vim-javascript'
Plug 'mxw/vim-jsx'
Plug 'w0rp/ale'
Plug 'altercation/vim-colors-solarized'
" call PlugInstall to install new plugins
call plug#end()
set termguicolors
colorscheme solarized

" basics
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on set number
set relativenumber
set incsearch
set ignorecase
set smartcase
set nohlsearch
set tabstop=4
set softtabstop=0
set shiftwidth=4
set expandtab
set nobackup
set noswapfile
set nowrap

" preferences
inoremap jk <ESC>
let mapleader = "\<Space>"
set pastetoggle=<F2>
" j/k will move virtual lines (lines that wrap)
noremap <silent> <expr> j (v:count == 0 ? 'gj' : 'j')
noremap <silent> <expr> k (v:count == 0 ? 'gk' : 'k')
" Stay in visual mode when indenting. You will never have to run gv after
" performing an indentation.
vnoremap < <gv
vnoremap > >gv
" Make Y yank everything from the cursor to the end of the line. This makes Y
" act more like C or D because by default, Y yanks the current line (i.e. the
" same as yy).
noremap Y y$
" navigate split screens easily
nmap <silent> <c-k> :wincmd k<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-j> :wincmd j<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-h> :wincmd h<CR>
nmap <silent> <c-l> :wincmd l<CR>
" change spacing for language specific
autocmd Filetype javascript setlocal ts=2 sts=2 sw=2

" plugin settings

" deoplete
let g:deoplete#enable_at_startup = 1
" use tab to forward cycle
inoremap <silent><expr><tab> pumvisible() ? "\<c-n>" : "\<tab>"
" use tab to backward cycle
inoremap <silent><expr><s-tab> pumvisible() ? "\<c-p>" : "\<s-tab>"
" Close the documentation window when completion is done
autocmd InsertLeave,CompleteDone * if pumvisible() == 0 | pclose | endif


"NERDTree
" How can I close vim if the only window left open is a NERDTree?
autocmd bufenter * if (winnr("$") == 1 && exists("b:NERDTree") && b:NERDTree.isTabTree()) | q | endif
" toggle NERDTree
map <C-n> :NERDTreeToggle<CR>
let g:NERDTreeChDirMode=2
let g:NERDTreeIgnore=['\.rbc$', '\~$', '\.pyc$', '\.db$', '\.sqlite$', '__pycache__', 'node_modules']
let g:NERDTreeSortOrder=['^__\.py$', '\/$', '*', '\.swp$', '\.bak$', '\~$']
let g:NERDTreeShowBookmarks=1
let g:nerdtree_tabs_focus_on_files=1
let g:NERDTreeMapOpenInTabSilent = '<RightMouse>'
set wildignore+=*/tmp/*,*.so,*.swp,*.zip,*.pyc,*.db,*.sqlite

" jsx
let g:jsx_ext_required = 0
```

I tried to run `:checkhealth` but the only warnings I got pertain to some Python provider errors. Would those be the issue?

Comment: Did you run `:PlugInstall` to install the plugins?

Comment: Yes I did, @bdesham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the issue here. I was using Solarized in Terminal mode (i.e. not in a GUI version like gvim or macvim), so I had to either manually configure the color palette or just use macvim.